# browsersync only refreshes if browser is the active window

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I have browser sync setup and running through gulp.  Although it automatically refreshes fine when the browser is the active and selected window, it doesn't if not.

This meant I can't have the editor and browser side by side and see continuous updates on the browser as I'm changing code in the editor. I keep on having to select the browser to see an update.  Is it possible to get it to work without having the browser as the active window. 
(on macOS Sierra).

gulpfile task:

```
// Browser sync server for live reload
gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init(
        [paths.css + "/**/*.css", paths.js + "*.js", paths.templates + '*.html'], {
            proxy: "localhost:8000",
            browser: 'chrome'
        });
```

.....

```
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function () {

    // gulp.watch(paths.sass + '/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(paths.less + '/**/*.less', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(paths.js + '/*.js', ['scripts']).on("change", reload);
    gulp.watch(paths.images + '/*', ['imgCompression']);
    gulp.watch(paths.templates + '/**/*.html').on("change", reload);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is not the code itself, but rather the fact that you need to save when in your editor to start the gulp task.

To explain some editors do the saving for you at specified instances. For example WebStorm saves automatically only when one stops writing and waits a specified amount of time to save and/or when focus from the application has shifted to another application, once the focus is shifted the saving is triggered and gulp can pick up on those changes, which in turn updates browsersync.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hmm I'm using pycharm though (same intellij platform as webstorm) which saves the same way.

Comment: Just save manually when you are ready to view the changes by pressing ctrl + s (windows) or command + s (mac) and that should solve your problem. Overall that's going to be the only workaround unless you switch ide

Comment: Thanks using command+S makes it work.  (Presumably by default, pycharm, webstorm etc... don't save until you move away from the app or pause editing for a period).